# Javascript: Web scraping data tables when site filters don't change anything in site elements

Tags: javascript, html, filter, screen-scraping, inspect

I am scraping the data from the "Scoring Leaders" table on this website: http://www.saahl.ca/leagues/stats_hockey.cfm?clientid=6601&leagueid=30336

I've successfully scraped the data using JS, having identified the #leaders ID on the  elements in the table through Inspect. The trouble is that I want to also scrape previous years data. You can select previous years using the dropdown menu above the table on the site and they show up on screen. However, when you select a previous year, the URL doesn't change, nor does anything inside inspect (that I can see). The inner text of the HTML elements changes, but nothing else that I can identify.

Is there any way to isolate something different for the scrape to target?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the selected value in the dropdown as identifier

You go to the url and scrape the data for 2021 / 2022 U15 Regular Season:

```
const trs = document.querySelectorAll(['tr.odd', 'tr.even'])
```

Now trs[0] contains:

[image: Results for first row]

You change the value in the select to 2020 / 2021 U15 Regular Season:

You perform the same query than before:

```
const trs = document.querySelectorAll(['tr.odd', 'tr.even'])
```

Now trs[0] contains:

[image: Results for first row]

Comment: Thanks for this. I really appreciate it. How would I do that if it's not the dropdown value I want to scrape?

Comment: If you don't want to scrape the data from an specific dropdown value just don't do it and only scrape the data for the values you are interested in

Comment: I might have been misunderstood - how do I set the code to scrape *the table* based on the value of the *dropdown*?

Comment: You said that: "The inner text of the HTML elements changes"

Comment: Correct. But nothing about the HTML elements or their IDs or CSS selectors change, so I don't know what to change in the code.

Comment: @newCoder The most common is that you don't have to change nothing in your code if you choose the right selectors

Comment: Thank you for updating. Is there a way to do this that is automated, though? Like I'm trying to set this up so that I don't have to physically go to the site.

Comment: @newCoder you could use Selenium, Puppeteer, Axios .... for automated it.